# PHP. Поиск данной по двумерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

у меня есть такой массив(как показано на картинке)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно находить данную по product_id

я пробывал сделать `var_dump(array_search('55117',(array)$purchaseWizardTemp->getData()));`

но мне возвращает false. будто он не видит его.

Как правильно написать код, чтобы он искал данную в двумерном массиве.
Цыкл я пытаюсь избежать. Слишком долго!

Comment: А вы считаете, что внутри встроенной функции не будет никакого цикла?

Comment: А может `$purchaseWizardTemp->getData()` ничего не возвращает? `55117` на картинке не вижу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего должно быть так:

```
$key = array_search('55117', array_column($purchaseWizardTemp->getData(), 'product_id'));
```

[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) - Возвращает массив из значений одного столбца входного массива. То есть по указанному имени ключа находит  значения. Ну а потом на основе них ищет уже в исходном массиве

**Заметка**: любые встроенные функции (array_search, array_column, array_map, array_filter и прочие) под капотом используют цикл. По-другому просто невозможно сделать операции над массивом.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вы бы ускорили процесс если бы прочитали
[Вот это](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php)

Плюс у вас `"product_id"` не совпадает с предложенным.

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        "id" => "1",
        "product_id" => "54117"
    ],
    1 => [
        "id" => "2",
        "product_id" => "53041"
    ]
];

foreach ($array as $arr){
    var_dump(array_search('54117', $arr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=array(array("id"=>"2563", "product_id"=>"54117", "group_id"=>"2130","ргice"=>"112.18", "cost"=>"0","qty"=>"1","sold"=>"1","shortdesc"=>"Serial Number: К62АТ93285SТ Model: МН22160ВН Part Number:СА07018-В38400РМ Firmware: 0РРОЗО-00430009 Date: МАК 20О9 Product of: Тhailand!РСВ Revision: СА26344-В33104ВА","brand_template"=>"Fujitsu","model"=>"МН22160ВН 62","pn_hddcode_2ndmodel"=>"СА07018-В38400РМ","mlc_fw_sitecode_dcm"=>"","spec_3"=>"","spec_4"=>"","уеаг"=>"0","flg"=>"0"), array("id"=>"25630", "product_id"=>"541187", "group_id"=>"21030","ргice"=>"112.180", "cost"=>"01","qty"=>"13","sold"=>"14","shortdesc"=>"Serial Number: К62АТ93285SТ Model: МН22160ВН Part Number:СА07018-В38400РМ Firmware: 0РРОЗО-00430009 Date: МАК 20О9 Product of: Тhailand!РСВ Revision: СА26344-В33104ВА","brand_template"=>"Fujitsu","model"=>"МН22160ВН 62","pn_hddcode_2ndmodel"=>"СА07018-В38400РМ","mlc_fw_sitecode_dcm"=>"","spec_3"=>"","spec_4"=>"","уеаг"=>"1","flg"=>"1"));
$chery=count($arr);

for($i = 0; $i <= $chery-1; $i++) {
if (array_key_exists('product_id', $arr[$i])) {
    if($arr[$i]['product_id']=='54117'){
        echo 'Найдено';
    }
}
}
```